# slider changing?

Tags: android

I am downloading image with its url with the Picasso library like below:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(myUrl).into(imageView);
```

and then I want to set this downloaded image into the daimagia slider like this

```
slide2.image(R.drawable.test);
```

but it just getting R.drawable.... ! How can set my downloaded image instead of R.drawable.test in order to load that image that was downloaded before ! please help

```
       slide2.image(R.drawable.test);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put string url iamge for example :
 slider.image("http//----ur url---")

Comment: Na dadash injuri nis

Comment: to tel bede  @haji_invoke

Comment: Idit eshtebahe ke

Comment: @haji_invoker 09196645329 be nam override proje to baram file src bede to tel

Comment: Hal shod dada merc